# Android BillingClient: handling onBillingServiceDisconnected before onBillingSetupFinished

Tags: android, play-billing-library

Given the code sample from https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate

```
billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
    override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
        if (billingResult.responseCode ==  BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.
        }
    }
    override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
        // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
        // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
    }
})
```

At a couple of customers the `onBillingServiceDisconnected` is called before `onBillingSetupFinished`. How should this be handled? The connection can't really be restarted as `startConnection` was never finished. Should `startConnection` be called anyway?

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: i implemented this answer: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169776730

Comment: @DavidMichaelGang How do you solve it, please? Can you post your implementation? I'm having a hard time jumping between devices, emulators and trying to sort this out.